# Extracting last occurence with regex

Tags: regex

I want to extract the last occurence of a date from my source file.
I use this expression to select a date:

`\d{1,2}(-|\/)\d{1,2}(-|\/)\d{2,4}`

How can I change it so that it only selects the last date that is encountered in the source file?

So for example, if this is the source:

```
19-04-2010 random text  
random text  
random text 19/5/1999  
25/12/1991 random text
```

I want the regex expression to return only:

```
25/12/1991
```

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Maybe you can get all the dates occurences and then chose the last one. Otherwise i doubt it coulb be done easily with a regex. What language are you using?

Comment: Treat the entire file as a single string; then search for an occurrence that has a negative lookahead (in other words: "find x that is not followed by anything followed by x"). That will be the last occurrence. How to implement that depends on the environment in which you do this (language).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this negative lookahead to make sure only last occurrence is matched:

```
\d{1,2}[-\/]\d{1,2}[-\/]\d{2,4}(?![\s\S]*?\d{1,2}[-\/]\d{1,2}[-\/]\d{2,4})
```

#### [Working Demo](http://regex101.com/r/mS7oD3)

- This is regex implementation of approach Floris commented i.e. `find x that is not followed by x"`
- I used `[\s\S]*?` since OP didn't specify tool/language of regex and I wasn't sure if any `DOTALL` equivalent flag is available.

Comment: You and I think alike... my comment explains your expression. Not sure I would have chosen `[\s\S]*?` for the "followed by anything" part of the expression. Can you explain?

Comment: I used `[\s\S]*?` since OP didn't specify tool/language of regex and I wasn't sure is any DOTALL equivalent is available.

Comment: You do need to explain how this works on the entire file - in other words you need a flag (in your demo, you used `g`).

Comment: `g` flag is not really needed, i updated demo link. Added some explanation but more is available on the demo link.

Comment: Just to clarify - does `[\s\S]*` span across multiple lines without any `DOTALL` flags? That's a good trick I didn't know.

Comment: Yes it does. Languages like Javascript where `DOTALL` is missing `[\s\S]*` trick is used to match text across multiple lines.